# how to get data of selected multiple radio button values from a Radio Group in android when a button is clicked

Tags: android, button, radio-button, submit, radio-group

how to get data of selected  multiple radio button values from a Radio Group in android when a button is click ..and display all the data..Code is working but stuck on ..when a button is submit and not getting the data.

here is the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Main9Activity extends Activity {
    RadioGroup RG1,RG2,RG3;
    RelativeLayout rl;
    public String chec="";
    Button bt;


    String status[] = { "Leave", "Late", "Absent", "Present" };
   // RadioGroup rg;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main9);
        LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
       // rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);





        for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++) {
            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[10];

           // rg = new RadioGroup(this);
            final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); // create the RadioGroup
            rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);// or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
            final TextView name=new TextView(this);
            String texid="16roll"+k;
            name.setText("16roll"+k);
            name.setId(R.id.RG2+k);

            int n = 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
                rg.addView(rb[i]);
               // rb[i].setText("Radio " + i);
                rb[i].setText(status[i]);

            }
            //rl.addView(rg);

            rl.addView(name);
            rl.addView(rg);
            rl.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
            rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int pos = rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                    //String roll="ytutyuty";
                    String roll=name.getText().toString();
                    switch (pos) {
                        case 0:

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  String.format("Leave" + roll), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            chec="Leave"+ roll;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.format("Late" +roll), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            chec="Late" +roll;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.format("Absent" +roll), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            chec="Absent" +roll;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("Present" +roll), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            chec="Present" +roll;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
       // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  String.format(chec), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  @Override
        //public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        // return true;
        // }


        bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  String.format(chec), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is way too complicated. Just include the radiogroup in the XML layout of the activity.

Then, on button click, set the onClick attribute to a function in your activity. There you do a lookup for the radiogroup:

`RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById (R.id.id_of_the_group);`

Then use this:
`int idOfSelected = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();`

Now you can do a switch-case for which one is selected:

```
switch(idOfSelected) {
    case R.id.radio1:
        // Do stuff
        break;
}
```

etc.etc.

Comment: @egom rest of the answer is still valid (how to get selected)